# When i run firebase funtion in browser i am getting 403 error

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

When i run firebase function from url i am getting this error : `Your client does not have permission to get URL /testing from this server.` , can anyone please help me why i am getting this error ? Here i have added my code for it

Here is my code for it

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

app.get('/testing', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ 'status': 0});
});
exports.widgets = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you export an HTTP type function, the name of the function becomes part of the URL.  You will probably want to use the path `/widgets/testing` to invoke your express route, since "widgets" is the name of the function.

Comment: I have done that, now i am getting this error : Cannot GET /testingtest